# Identify peers in cluster using hash

Tags: p2p, ipfs

Services like tor add ipfs use hash to identify peers but how they managed to keep track which keys point to which. Do they key track of which key points to which site (which would be a disaster for tor) or by using some algorithm to locate peers.